# Django 1.8 How Drop certain tables using manage.py?

Tags: python, django, data-migration

I'm having a real bad time using `manage.py` to drop certain tables of the database, the project is already running.

the only way I found is accessing the tables by:

> python manage.py dbshell

but again, not sure how to drop the tables.

Comment: Do you literally want to nuke the entire database and start from scratch? Your title says "all tables", but your question body says "certain tables".

Comment: @Chris just fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's [`dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#dbshell) drops you into the command-line client for your configured database. Some commands will be database-specific, but dropping tables is pretty consistent across major databases.

Once you're in there you should be able to

```sql
DROP TABLE foo;
```

to drop the `foo` table. You will probably need to drop tables in a particular order since they may have dependencies on each other, e.g. by foreign key.

(Alternatively you could use the `CASCADE` parameter to drop dependent tables, but if you're not *very* careful this could *really* ruin your night. In my opinion it's better to go slowly and deliberately, dropping one table at a time.)

**Of course, always back your database up before doing this kind of thing!**